# sending data from activity to Intentservice

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

my needs is to send data from activity to IntentService

(from class that extends activity, to class that extends IntentService)

i successed to send to sample service, by using BroadcastReciver, but i want to **extend IntentService class** and not service

someone know how can i do that?

from

> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>   ...
>   }

to

> public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
>   ...
>   }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the data in an `Intent` extra that you use with the `startService()` call to start your `IntentService`. Then, the `IntentService` can read that extra in `onHandleIntent()`.

Comment: so i dont need to create the broadcastReciver in the IntentService at all?

Comment: @ofir_aghai: No. Moreover, having a `BroadcastReceiver` in an `IntentService` would be a significant "code smell" IMHO. Note that this same technique works for a regular `Service`, though you would retrieve the extras in `onStartCommand()` instead of `onHandleIntent()`.

Comment: now if you can i apprichiate if you can explain me the last part with the `onStartCommand()`

Comment: @CommonsWare Can I send data to `IntentService` if it's already running?

Comment: @DhavalPatel: Outside of perhaps a cancellation signal, I cannot think of a case where this makes sense for `IntentService`. In terms of implementation, that's beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow comment. You may wish to post a separate Stack Overflow question outlining your use case.