# Why does my service class receive null values?

Tags: java, android, networking, service

I have a `PlayerActivity` class, and a `PlayerConnect` class.

Previously, I used `PlayerActivity` class to start a thread that would run `PlayerConnect`. I recently found that the thread misbehaves a little, and have been recommended to use services (for this: IntentServices).

**Problem:** My logs tell me that the IP, name, and init are *null, null, 0*, which should not be the case as they are supposed to be set before the point of starting the service. Logs also tell me that it's failing to connect to the localhost, which I think it's defaulting to because it doesn't have a set IP to try.

Am I correctly referencing the `PlayerConnect` class in my Intent?

**PlayerActivity:**

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    InetAddress hostIP;
    String playerName;
    int playerInitiative = -1;
    boolean denied = false;
    boolean started = false;
    PlayerConnect playerConnect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!(playerName.equals("")) && playerInitiative > -1) {
                    try {
                        if (!(hostIPString.equals(""))) {
                            hostIP = InetAddress.getByName(hostIPString);
                            if(!(started)) {
                                playerConnect = new PlayerConnect();
                                playerConnect.SetHostIP(hostIP);
                                playerConnect.SetPlayerName(playerName);
                                playerConnect.SetPlayerInit(playerInitiative);
                                denied = playerConnect.GetDenied();
                                started = true;
                            }

                            else {
                                playerConnect.SetHostIP(hostIP);
                                playerConnect.SetPlayerName(playerName);
                                playerConnect.SetPlayerInit(playerInitiative);
                                denied = playerConnect.GetDenied();
                            }


                            if (denied)
                            {
                                started = false;
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Intent playerConnectIntent =
                                        new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, playerConnect.getClass());
                                startService(playerConnectIntent);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.i("LOG", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**PlayerConnect:**

```
public class PlayerConnect extends IntentService {

    public PlayerConnect() {
        super("PlayerConnect");
    }

    InetAddress hostIP;
    String playerName;
    int playerInitiative;
    boolean denied = false;

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            SendPlayerData(hostIP, playerName, playerInitiative);
    }

    private void SendPlayerData(InetAddress IP, String name, int init) {
        try {
            int port = 8080;
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(IP, port), 3000);
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            if (socket.isConnected())
            {
                output.writeUTF(name);
                output.writeInt(init);
                output.close();
                socket.close();

                Log.i("LOG", "client socket connected");
            }

            if (socket.isClosed())
            {
                stopSelf();

                Log.i("LOG", "client socket closed");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            denied = true;
            Log.i("LOG", e.toString());
            Log.i("LOG", IP + name + init);

        }
    }

    public void SetHostIP(InetAddress host)
    {
        hostIP = host;
    }

    public void SetPlayerName(String name)
    {
        playerName = name;
    }

    public void SetPlayerInit(int init)
    {
        playerInitiative = init;
    }

    public boolean GetDenied()
    {
        return denied;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you never want to construct a `Service` subclass yourself (`new PlayerConnect()`). That's the system's job. The one it gives you in response to a `startService()` call will be completely different from the one you get back from the constructor, so it won't have any of the data you added to it. You need to add your data to `playerConnectIntent`, and retrieve it in `onHandleIntent()`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18301029/6759241) for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[greeble31](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6759241/greeble31) *Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942894/why-does-my-service-class-receive-null-values/59023669#comment104145647_58942894) helped me a lot, so I'm making it the answer for future readers. **Thank you.***

> No, you never want to construct a Service subclass yourself (new PlayerConnect()). That's the system's job. The one it gives you in response to a startService() call will be completely different from the one you get back from the constructor, so it won't have any of the data you added to it. You need to add your data to playerConnectIntent, and retrieve it in onHandleIntent().